# Symfony, Monolog and Slack : how can I format notifications?

Tags: symfony, slack, slack-api, symfony-3.4, monolog

On a Symfony 3.4 project, I want to send notifications to a Slack channel via Monolog. I use the SlackHandler and it works well but now I want to find a way to format my notification, [using Slack's recommendations](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages). Is it possible ?

For now, each key I send is a new field title and each value associated is a field. Can I directly change the content of "Message" ? Can I also hide the "Level" entry ? I try to use 'fields' from $attachment in SlackRecord.php, but no success so far.

Many, many thanks.

Extracts of what I've done so far. My yaml config:

```
    # monolog.yml
       reviews:
        type: slack
        token: '%token%'
        channel: "#mychannel"
        bot_name: 'My bot'
        icon_emoji: :sports_medal:
        level: info
        channels: [reviews]
        include_extra: true
```

And in my controller :

```
     // ...

    $message = [
      'a' => $post->getTitle(),
      'b' => $ur->getInterventionRating(),
      "fields" => [
             "title": "Priority",
                "value": "High",
                "short": false ], ];

      $this->container->get('monolog.logger.myChannel')->info("test", $message);
```

Comment: Try capturing the output JSON you're sending to Slack and paste it into their message tester here to see what might be off about your structure: https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Yep_It's_Meno :(